# change download folder based on website from which I download

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, download, google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to change Downloads folder in Google Chrome (or any other browser) on the fly, based on the website from which I download?

Example: I start downloading on `facebook.com` and it downloads the file in `~/Downloads/Facebook`. If I start the download from `stackoverflow.com` than the file is downloaded into`~/Downloads/Stackoverflow`.

How can I achieve this? Is there a plugin that does that?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to different SE sites - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236525/change-download-folder-based-on-website-from-which-i-download

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Downloads Router](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloads-router/fgkboeogiiklpklnjgdiaghaiehcknjo/) on Google Chrome to achieve download organization by domain, mimetype or filename.

Description from the Chrome Web store:

> Downloads Router springs into action whenever you start downloading a file. It looks at the filename, filetype, or origin domain (source website) of the item, and matches this information against rules that you define on the extension's Options page. Should a matching rule exist, a "suggestion" is sent to the browser, indicating where it should save the file; this suggestion may however be overridden, as for instance when you use the "Save As..." feature.

Comment: Spot on. Just what I was looking for. 